# Integral proof identity

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, definite-integrals

\begin{equation}
f(\infty)+f(-\infty)=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^{+}}\epsilon \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dt f(t) e^{-\epsilon|t|}
\end{equation}
I assume this is a smooth functino $f(\tau)$ that intuitively this relation holds, but unable to proof this

Comment: Do you assume that $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x)$ exist and are finite? Or at least exist in such a way that we don't have $\infty - \infty$ situation on the left hand side?

Comment: Yes, I assume it's a continuous function which exist and finite for all values

Comment: **Hint:** Change of variable $u = \epsilon t$ and using Lebesgue's dominated convergent theorem

Answer (score 0):

Here's an elementary argument.

Write $L=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$. For any $\delta>0$ there exists $k$ such that $|f(t)-L|<\delta$ for all $t\geq k$. Then $\def\e{\epsilon}$
\begin{align}
\e\,\int_k^\infty f(t)\,e^{-\e t}\,dt\leq \e\,\int_k^\infty (L+\delta)\,e^{-\e t}
=\,(L+\delta)\,e^{-\e k}.
\end{align}
So, using a similar inequality to the left, we get
$$\tag1
L-\delta\leq \limsup_{\e\to0}\e\,\int_k^\infty f(t)\,e^{-\e t}\,dt\leq L+\delta. 
$$
As $f$ is bounded, there is $c>0$ such that $|f(t)| \leq c$ for all $t$, and so
$$
\e\,\bigg|\int_0 ^k f(t)\,e^{-\e t}\,dt\bigg|
\leq \e\,\int_0 ^k |f(t)|\,e^{-\e t}\,dt\leq c\,\e\,\int_0^k e^{-\e t}\,dt=c\,e^{-\e k},
$$
so
$$\tag2
\lim_{\e\to0}\e\,\int_0 ^k f(t)\,e^{-\e t}\,dt=0. 
$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$,
$$
L-\delta\leq\limsup_{\e\to0}\int_0^\infty f(t)\,e^{-\e t}\,dt\leq L+\delta. 
$$
As this can be done for any $\delta>0$, we conclude that
$$
\limsup_{\e\to0}\int_0^\infty f(t)\,e^{-\e t}\,dt=L.
$$
The same computations can be carried with $\liminf$, so this shows that the limit exists and
$$\tag3
\lim_{\e\to0}\int_0^\infty f(t)\,e^{-\e t}\,dt=L.
$$
Now the equality
$$
\lim_{t\to-\infty}f(t)=\lim_{\e\to0}\e\int_{-\infty}^0 f(t)\,e^{-\e|t|}\,dt
$$
can be obtained from $(3)$ by the substitution $t\to-t$